# Custom function with dplyr mutate or summarise for different levels within a factor?

Tags: r, dplyr

Here is some example data:

```
library(car)
library(dplyr)
    df1 <- mtcars %>%
                group_by(cyl, gear) %>%
                summarise(
                    newvar = sum(wt)
                )
# A tibble: 8 x 3
# Groups:   cyl [?]
    cyl  gear newvar
  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1     4     3   2.46
2     4     4  19.0 
3     4     5   3.65
4     6     3   6.68
5     6     4  12.4 
6     6     5   2.77
7     8     3  49.2 
8     8     5   6.74
```

What if I then wanted to apply a custom function calculating the difference between the newvar values for cars with 3 or 5 gears for each level of cylinder?

```
df2 <- df1 %>%  mutate(Diff = newvar[gear == "3"] - newvar[gear == "5"])
```

or with summarise?

```
df2 <- df1 %>%  summarise(Diff = newvar[gear == "3"] - newvar[gear == "5"])
```

There must be a way to apply functions for different levels within different factors?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example code is most of the way there. You can do:

```
df1 %>% 
    mutate(Diff = newvar[gear == "3"] - newvar[gear == "5"])
```

Or:

```
df1 %>% 
    summarise(Diff = newvar[gear == "3"] - newvar[gear == "5"])
```

Logical subsetting still works in `mutate()` and `summarise()` calls like with any other vector.

Note that this works because after your `summarise()` call in your example code, `df1` is still grouped by `cyl`, otherwise you would need to do a `group_by()` call to create the correct grouping.

Comment: While I was writing this answer it looks like you updated your example code to match this anyway - is there something you don't like about this solution? You might have to update your question to explain why this doesn't meet your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I think I had updated to add "newvar" the same time that you did!

Answer (score 2):

An option is to `spread` into 'wide' format and then do the `-`

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
   filter(gear %in% c(3, 5) ) %>% 
   spread(gear, newvar) %>% 
   transmute(newvar = `3` - `5`)
# A tibble: 3 x 2
# Groups:   cyl [3]
#    cyl newvar
#  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1     4  -1.19
#2     6   3.90
#3     8  42.5
```